# нету pgadmin в браузере на сервере

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

установил на удаленный сервер (debian 12) postgresql с ним все хорошо ,потом установил pgadmin4 ,но когда захожу со СВОЕГО КОМПЬЮТЕРА в браузер и пишу ip cервер /pgadmin4/ пишет 404 not found ,пробовал редактировать разные конфиги чтобы можно было подключаться с разных ip не помогло , apache если что работает ,надеюсь поможете

Answer (score 0):

попробуй для начала проверить есть пинг к твоему серваку
потом ты должен запустить у себя на локальном pgadmin 4 и уже от туда подключиться к бд. и у тебя скорее всего может быть не запущен pgadmin4 и у тебя скорее всего он не запущен на серваке и поэтому ты не можешь подрубиться

Comment: не очень тебя понял , ты имел ввиду поставить pgadmin не на сервер ,а на пк и с пк конектиться к бд ?

Comment: я думал о том , что он может быть не запущен ,но как это проверить я не зхнаю сервиса такого же нету чтобы через systemctl запустить ,а сам apache работает

Comment: смотри у тебя возможно просто нет подключение к серваку и поэтому рн у тебя он не может подрубиться к pgadmin

Comment: да сервак то сам работает

Comment: ты так запускал pgadmin sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh

Comment: написал ,он сконфигурирывал apache конфиг там запустил все и написал pgadmin доступен по ip 127.0.0.1/pgadmin4 я захожу с пк и 404 not fund

Comment: 127.0.0.1 это же localhost  и он доступен только на на серваке  http://Your-Server-IP-address/pgadmin4

Comment: в том то и дело ,я со своего компьютера пытаюсь туда зайти

Comment: https://ruvds.com/ru/helpcenter/postgresql-pgadmin-ubuntu/ посмотри здесь

Comment: и попробуй все таки пингануть сервак  ping <адрес сервера> -n 10